Prove that minimal disconnecting set is a cut. (Definitions included in the body).
Definitions
1.) Given a connected graph $G$, the minimal disconnecting set is the set of minimum number of edges that needs to be removed so that $G$ has more than one component.
2.) A cut is a set of edges of $G$ such that there exists a proper subset $S$ of vertex of $G$ such that it is incident to one vertex in $S$ and the other vertex in $V-S $.
3.) A disconnecting set is a collection of edges whose deletion makes a connected graph $G$ have more than one component.
Question
Let $G$ be a connected graph. Prove that every minimal disconnecting set of $G$ is a cut. Also show that every disconnecting set need not be a cut.
Thoughts
If $G$ is a given graph, take the disconnecting set to be the complete set of edges. Then this edge set is certainly not a cut. But is there any non trivial examples to show this fact.
Also, how to proceed to show that every minimal disconnecting set is a cut, I don't have any intuition on how to proceed.
